# Verilog error when making alu : is not a constant

Tags: verilog

I am making an ALU, and I get an error.  Why does it happen? The error message is:

> sel is not a constant

```
module ALU(A,B,sel,aluout);
    input [3:0] A, B;
    input sel;
    output [7:0] aluout;
    wire c1;
    
    if(sel==0)
        begin
        fourbit_adder(A,B,Ci(1'b0),aluout,Co(c1));
        end
    else 
        begin 
        mult4(A,B,aluout);
        end

endmodule

module TB_multiplier(
);
    
    reg [3:0] m;
    reg [3:0] q;
    reg Sel;
    wire [7:0] p;
    
    ALU mult4_module(.p(p), .m(m), .q(q), .Sel(Sel));
    
    initial begin
    m = 4'b0000; q = 4'b0000; Sel = 1'b0;
    
    #5 m = 6; q = 7; Sel = 0;
    #5 m = 6; q = 7; Sel = 1;
    #5 m = 3; q = 5; Sel = 0;
    #5 m = 3; q = 5; Sel = 1;
    
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

`fourbit_adder` is a block of hardware. `mult4` is another block of hardware. Your code is asking for `fourbit_adder` to be present when `sel` is 0 and `mult4` to be present when `sel` is 1. That breaks the laws of physics. Hardware cannot magically appear and disappear.

You need to *instantiate* both blocks unconditionally:

```
fourbit_adder(A,B,Ci(1'b0),aluout_fourbit_adder,Co(c1));
mult4(A,B,aluout_mult4);
```

and then drive your `aluout` output using a multiplexor, whose output is selected by your `sel` input, eg something like:

```
assign aluout = sel ? aluout_mult4 : aluout_fourbit_adder;
```

(I have not tested this. This is just to give you a general impression.)